# insert blocks with ExclusiveLock on index in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, locking

Database - Google Cloud SQL, Postgresql 11.

We have a partitioned table, with one of the partitions, which is the most active, having 4 bln rows (3Tb).
The table has several columns being a primary key and one of the columns is `json` with a `gin` index.

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
    key_col1,
    key_col2,
    message_type text NOT NULL,
    message jsonb NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT messages_pkey PRIMARY KEY (key_col1, key_col2, message_type)
)
PARTITION BY LIST (message_type);

CREATE INDEX gin_index ON messages USING gin (message);

CREATE TABLE messages_type_1 PARTITION OF messages FOR VALUES IN ('MessageType1')
```

The table is frequently inserted to, with `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.

Lately, some of the inserts started blocking. It goes on for around 25 minutes. then it resolves, all the inserts that have heaped up get done, and some other insert gets blocked.

This query

```
SELECT a.datname,
         l.relation::regclass,
         l.transactionid,
         l.mode,
         l.GRANTED,
         a.usename,
         a.query,
         a.query_start,
         age(now(), a.query_start) AS "age",
         a.pid
FROM pg_stat_activity a
JOIN pg_locks l ON l.pid = a.pid
WHERE MODE <> 'RowExclusiveLock'
ORDER BY a.query_start;
```

shows these locks

```
| relation  | transactions |      mode     | granted | query         | query_start
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [NULL]        [NULL]        ExclusiveLock   true     INSERT INTO ...  2020-07-28 19:20:37
 [NULL]        [NULL]        ExclusiveLock   true     INSERT INTO ...  2020-07-28 19:20:37
 [NULL]       1480644902     ExclusiveLock   true     INSERT INTO ...  2020-07-28 19:20:37
 gin_index     [NULL]        ExclusiveLock   true     INSERT INTO ...  2020-07-28 19:20:37
```

These are autovacuum settings

```
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor 0.1
autovacuum_analyze_threshold    50
autovacuum_freeze_max_age   200000000
autovacuum_max_workers  3
autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age 400000000
autovacuum_naptime  1min
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay    20ms
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit    -1
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor  0.2
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold 50
autovacuum_work_mem -1

vacuum_cleanup_index_scale_factor   0.1
vacuum_cost_delay   0
vacuum_cost_limit   1000
vacuum_cost_page_dirty  20
vacuum_cost_page_hit    1
vacuum_cost_page_miss   10
vacuum_defer_cleanup_age    0
vacuum_freeze_min_age   50000000
vacuum_freeze_table_age 150000000
vacuum_multixact_freeze_min_age 5000000
vacuum_multixact_freeze_table_age   150000000
```

Are these exclusive locks normal? How could I debug this further?

Comment: Any chance you may be running into the "immediate cleanup cycle" detailed here?  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-implementation.html#GIN-FAST-UPDATE

Comment: @MikeOrganek it's said there that proper use of autovacuum should help with this. I updated the question with autovacuum settings.

Comment: To clarify, I am just guessing that these pauses are caused by autovacuum.  I suggest setting `log_autovacuum_min_duration` to 5000ms or so and then check the PostgreSQL logs to see if you are locking because of vacuum.  I *think* that with 4bn rows, the `autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor 0.2` means that you need 800M dirty tuples before `autovacuum` triggers.  Also, this is not as much about actual `vacuum` as it is about keeping the gin pending list under control.

Comment: Actually I checked that at some moments when inserts where locked, all the autovacuums were running on other tables.